# How can Standard User change file associations in Windows 2000?

Tags: windows, file-association, windows-2000

One of my clients is still running Win2K server with a host of Win2K workstations. And no net admin, due to the downturn of the economy over the years. I'm sort of helping out. Out of my depth, but I am a loyal foot soldier.

A problem I encounter rather too often is a user double-clicks on a file in Explorer and then either gets no action, or the wrong program to run. It's a case of a missing or out-of-date file association. The current cure is to temporarily upgrade the user from Standard to Power, do the FA switch and then change back. As Winnie would whine, 'Oh, bother!'

At any rate, I thought I'd ask here. Is there a method/program to run without the rigamarole FROM the Standard Users account on the workstation to edit/add a file association? I assume the program route would involve RunAs. I 'believe' most of the workstations run the RunAs service, but I could be wrong. I understand that's required, if there is to be a solution.

Any help accepted with thanks. GM

NOTE: Seems wassociate from http://www.xs4all.nl/~wstudios/Associate/index.html can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) a whirl. It can clean up broken file associations via the registry, among many other things. It's a great program to always have in your toolbox regardless.

Comment: while i concur regarding the usefulness of the program, you should point to the slim or portable build of Ccleaner because the standard installer will by default add a silly search bar to your web browser (which is not very nice).